# Google Vr Video view Error

Tags: android, video, google-vr

after

```
videoWidgetView.loadVideo(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.115:8888/googlemap/MageComp.mp4"));
```

or

```
videoWidgetView..loadVideoFromAsset("3dtest3.mp4");
```

**3dtest3.mp4** is stored in my asset folder

I am getting this error on run time.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VideoTexture.getIsTextureSet()' on a null object reference
at com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoPlayerInternal.prepareFrame(VrVideoPlayerInternal.java:318)
at com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoRenderer.onDrawFrame(VrVideoRenderer.java:57)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1566)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1272)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out on passing the options object as a parameter in the method call. 
The object carries relevant information around the source (asset/HLS) and around the type of VR video (360/ 3D 360).